# how to add and delete rows of elements in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have row of elements like this:

```
<template>
    <div style="width: 150px; height:60px; overflow:hidden; margin-top:.5%; z-index:999; " >
        <input name="name[]" type="text"  placeholder="Name" style="height:40px; width:250px; border:none; margin-left:800px; position:absolute; border-radius:10px; font-size:20px; z-index:999; " >
        <input name="val[]" type="text"  placeholder="Value" style="height:40px; width:98px; border:none; margin-left:1070px; position:absolute; border-radius:10px; text-align:center; color:#006ca5; font-size:20px; z-index:999; ">
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    function addrow() {
        $(template).attr('id', 'id' + i).appendTo('#appendloc');
        i++;
    };
```

appendLoc is defined as:

```
<div id="appendloc">
</div>
```

round button:

Now, I have a round button() which on click, calls the addrow function which is how i am able to add rows of the template. But now, I want to add a '-' similar to round button to every row of the added template which on clicked will delete the corresponding row. It seems i might have to keep every row by index, so that it will enable a specific row to be deleted. Can anybody please suggest that I can go? I am learning javascript, so I will appreciate if any expert comments on this.

Thanks a lot

Comment: Say you have a '-' button in each row.  You can tell which row it's in inside the "click" event handler (either `this` or `event.target` will give a reference to the clicked button, from there use javascript api to find appropriate parent/sibling elements), and delete elements that are in that row.  You don't need to use IDs.

Comment: Can you use jquery here ?

Comment: Hi James, could you post code snippet for it? I got your point, but do I have to run a loop to find all siblings or can i use delete the 2 siblings explicitely? please help with code. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert, but can try to give a solution. Try the code given below. It will delete the corresponding row when a "-" button will be clicked.

```js
function boxrem() {
  $(this).closest("template").remove();
}
```

If you wish to re-insert the deleted element later, use .detatch() instead of .remove()

Comment: Hi Pranav,I tried but no avail  <i class="fas fa-minus-circle" aria-hidden="true" style="background-color:transparent; color:rgb(50, 167, 230);" style="height:40px; width:250px; border-radius:10px;" onclick="boxrem()"></i> Then, deleting means I should be able to get all elements in the remaining rows too when i submit the form

Comment: @arnabdasgupta I am sorry. I misread the question. I have changed the code in snippet.